# List all my Azure websites using an Azure Powershell Function

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

Im testing the new Azure Functions, and would like to write a function that return all my Azure Websites. But needless to say I run into some problems, and documantation is still minimal.

**run.ps1**

```
# Get the input request
$in = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Output "Loading..."

Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $in.SubscriptionId | Select-AzureRmSubscription
$Result = Get-AzureWebsite
Write $Result
```

This function take the subscription id as a parameter, and is supposed to list the available websites. But I get this exception.

```
2017-06-13T12:43:57.763 Get-AzureRmSubscription : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
```

So I tried to add `Login-AzureRmAccount` but then I get.

```
2017-06-13T12:45:04.959 Login-AzureRmAccount : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

And that is where I stand now.

**Update**

After help from @4c74356b41 I now am able to login. My code for logging in looks like this.

```
$subscriptionId = "<SubscriptionId>"
$tenantid = "<TenantId>"
$clientid = "<ApplicationId>"
$password = "<Password>"
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientid, $userPassword
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential
```

I can see that this work when I test the code. But as soon as I add this line.

```
Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
```

I get this exception.

```
Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription id <SubscriptionId> doesn't exist.
Parameternavn: id
At line:11 char:1
+ Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SelectAzureSubscriptionCommand
```

I also tried to add this line.

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionId $subscriptionId | Select-AzureRmSubscription
```

Which look like is working, it only thows a warning `WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'Common'` but still list the correct subscription details without any exceptions.

Then when I try

```
Get-AzureWebsite
```

I get this exception.

```
Get-AzureWebsite : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription.
At line:15 char:1
+ Get-AzureWebsite
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureWebsite], ApplicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.GetAzureWebsiteCommand
```

Comment: Also, did you supply any parameters?  i.e. if you have multiple subscriptions associated with your account, you may want to run `Login-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionId $in.SubscriptionId` to ensure you log into the correct tenant/subscription.

Comment: No, I did not. I ran it through the Azure Portal and only saw console output. Like this example https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dfinke/images/master/PowerShellAzureFunctionApp.png

Comment: Ah; that may explain the com error; i.e. it's trying to open a window whilst restricted to console.  Try passing a Credential parameter with your details.  See answer for related code sample.

Comment: @Martin `Get-AzureWebsite` is classic cmdlet, you should use `Get-AzureRmWebApp` to list your webapp. You could check my answer.

Comment: @Martin Does cmdlet `Get-AzureRmWebApp` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, how do you expect to work with your subscription without authenticating? would you like anybody to be able to modify your resources without any validation at all? so you need to authenticate before doing anything.

Working with powershell in Azure Function is no different from working with powershell on your machine (except module management).

To login you could use [service principal auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal) ang login with something like:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionName $name `
   -Credential ([pscredential]::new($clientid,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force)))
```

you can replace variables (hardcoded in the code) with environment variables.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. I thought since the Azure Function already requires a key in order to run I thought that was the authentication needed.

Comment: no, azure function is not aware of your azure subscription ;)

Comment: Since I'm new to this. Can I create a service user for this? Do I then have to create an Azure Active Directory in order for that to work?

Comment: that's a lot of questions. that link i've provided covers the process end to end. and you cant have azure subscription without azure ad, its created when you create your subscription (so its already there for you)

Comment: I have updated my question. I can now successfully login. But I get an exception saying `The subscription id <SubscriptionId> doesn't exist` Got any clue?

Comment: what Walter said, but you really need to open another question instead of redoing this one. just accept the answer and start a new thread. @Martin

Comment: Thanks, your login answer really solved it, and Walter's `Get-AzureRmWebApp` closed it. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Add 4c74356b41's answer, `Get-AzureWebsite` is an Azure Classic mode cmdlet. Now, you login your ARM subscription, so, it requires you login classic subscription. `Select-AzureSubscription` is a classic cmdlet that use to select classic subscription.

In Azure ARM mode, website is renamed Webapp, you could check  [Azure App Service announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-app-service/).

So, if you want to list your all webapp, you should use cmdlet `Get-AzureRmWebApp`.

More information please refer to this link: [Using Azure Resource Manager-Based PowerShell to Manage Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-app-azure-resource-manager-powershell#managing-app-service-web-apps).